# Google App Engine inbound mail throws soft fail error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mime-message

Google App Engine **inbound mail** throws soft fail error.

**Received-SPF**: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning abc@xyz.com does not designate xx.xxx.xx.xxx as permitted sender).

Unable to parse inbound mail **recepients** (cc,bcc,to) of mime message.

I have not enabled **security-constraint** in the web.xml file for the **/_ah/mail/** path,
however security-constraint is enabled for path **/*** with **transport-guarantee CONFIDENTIAL**

Added servlet and filter mapping as follows

```
<filter>
<filter-name>InboundMailFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.InboundMailFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>InboundMailFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any solution would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to debug it later, if mailhandler servlet returns HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, we get the above mentioned spf fail message, issue is not caused due to security-constraint, filter, servlet mappings